# Confusion about critical points of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: http://puu.sh/ld1Gu/cf3f74803a.png]

I'm a bit confused about why x=+/-1 are critical points but y=+/-1 aren't critical points. Can someone help clarify it for me?

Answer (score 0):

The partial $\partial f/\partial y=0$ iff $y=0$, since the other factors are strictly positive (the exponential and $x^2+y^2+1$), so $y=\pm 1$ is impossible. Note the the partial derivatives are not symmetric, the minus sign is different.

Comment: Oh my... I think I was looking at the formulas wrong....It all makes sense now hahaha. Thanks for clarifying it for me!